# Let's Encrypt with multi Stores and multi domain renew error

Tags: ssl, magento2.3.7, ssl-certificate

My web server is (Apache2 version 2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
The operation system Server Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Host Provider private server: Digital Ocean

I can log in to the root shell.

I don't use a control panel.

certbot version 0.27.0

I am using Magento 2. I have set up Let's Encrypt to work with Magento multi-websites. site1 and site2 90 days ago when trying to renew I get the following error codes.

Attempting to renew cert (site1.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/site1com.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. site2.us (HTTP-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized:: The client lacks sufficient authorization:: 159.65.238.59: Invalid response from https://site2.us/catalogsearch/result/?q=well+known+acme+challenge+T8jQdISFBmpXsVw5nsEK14nEHcPkPW6FbUon9joMsBg&404=1: "\r\n<!doctype html>\r\n\r\n \r\n \n\tvar BASE_URL = WEB_URL = 'https://site2". Skipping.

I have the following directory on my server in the root public .well-known/acme-challenge.

It appears to be looking in my Magento website in the search result for validation.

Any help will be wonderful.

> y two domain names are shop.room801.com 1 and shop.explorotica.us

I ran the following command: sudo certbot renew

Output:

Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 20 Nov 2023 16:11:58 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 1639
Connection: keep-alive
Boulder-Requester: 85082002
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, no-cache
Link: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory;rel="index"
Replay-Nonce: v0bMowfiCcF_KpzhMFrfbTnhI9VKYhoQ3CNBj8LA1OlLWXLJVz8
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800

{
"identifier": {
"type": "dns",
"value": "shop.explorotica.us"
},
"status": "invalid",
"expires": "2023-11-27T16:11:51Z",
"challenges": [
{
"type": "http-01",
"status": "invalid",
"error": {
"type": "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized",
"detail": "159.65.238.59: Invalid response from https://shop.explorotica.us/catalogsearch/result/?q=well+known+acme+challenge+obUpeBmCy6dZnhtnwmgh2nc6xiwE2JY1quTEuG3SuSU\u0026404=1: "\r\n\u003c!doctype html\u003e\r\n\u003chtml class=\"use-header2\" lang=\"en\"\u003e\r\n    \u003chead \u003e\r\n        \u003cscript\u003e\n\tvar BASE_URL = WEB_URL = 'https://shop.e"",
"status": 403
},
"url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/285750384116/1rXJtw",
"token": "obUpeBmCy6dZnhtnwmgh2nc6xiwE2JY1quTEuG3SuSU",
"validationRecord": [
{
"url": "http://shop.explorotica.us/.well-known/acme-challenge/obUpeBmCy6dZnhtnwmgh2nc6xiwE2JY1quTEuG3SuSU",
"hostname": "shop.explorotica.us",
"port": "80",
"addressesResolved": [
"159.65.238.59"
],
"addressUsed": "159.65.238.59"
},
{
"url": "https://shop.explorotica.us/catalogsearch/result/?q=well+known+acme+challenge+obUpeBmCy6dZnhtnwmgh2nc6xiwE2JY1quTEuG3SuSU\u0026404=1",
"hostname": "shop.explorotica.us",
"port": "443",
"addressesResolved": [
"159.65.238.59"
],
"addressUsed": "159.65.238.59"
}
],
"validated": "2023-11-20T16:11:52Z"
}
]
}
2023-11-20 11:11:56,940:DEBUG:acme.client:Storing nonce: v0bMowfiCcF_KpzhMFrfbTnhI9VKYhoQ3CNBj8LA1OlLWXLJVz8
2023-11-20 11:11:56,941:DEBUG:acme.client:JWS payload:
b''
2023-11-20 11:11:56,943:DEBUG:acme.client:Sending POST request to https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/285750384126:
{
"protected": "eyJhbGciOiAiUlMyNTYiLCAia2lkIjogImh0dHBzOi8vYWNtZS12MDIuYXBpLmxldHNlbmNyeXB0Lm9yZy9hY21lL2FjY3QvODUwODIwMDIiLCAibm9uY2UiOiAidjBiTW93ZmlDY0ZfS3B6aE1GcmZiVG5oSTlWS1lob1EzQ05CajhMQTFPbExXWExKVno4IiwgInVybCI6ICJodHRwczovL2FjbWUtdjAyLmFwaS5sZXRzZW5jcnlwdC5vcmcvYWNtZS9hdXRoei12My8yODU3NTAzODQxMjYifQ",
"signature": "WMFtYO8PWcA6dKw87QgiRNVPRyHbDIQgcXmpIK7O1mPg_KkQv3PIp-CqCsu51bUF5AyX-ZOERx9zz71zSxBBINIHZVvEWvh0kMbQd7x5BDCtvyyIY48hcF0bY6b2pqXpIeP6yu3fl0GKA6N-cfznxfmYQjeaqx5B0jhBfSvqq8UuX6w6H0U-yhRfPEWRkrEB99kMVhBXxf9jO2jVJORpMQD9sHZhSfN-7cTrWjW_5bnTkQsItsPrHcmrMrIAoEzdgqfwD5FKJGweexpkXInXKW1sURVk1l7qZ7kPIfnnxMcyXbWq7gCMnHmRazGYmbcWViysPLJqzkgIBcVUgcTcjA",
"payload": ""
}
2023-11-20 11:11:56,990:DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:443 "POST /acme/authz-v3/285750384126 HTTP/1.1" 200 1621
2023-11-20 11:11:56,991:DEBUG:acme.client:Received response:
HTTP 200
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 20 Nov 2023 16:11:58 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 1621
Connection: keep-alive
Boulder-Requester: 85082002
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, no-cache
Link: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory;rel="index"
Replay-Nonce: v0bMowfisrPp6g35giCZu_YsSwNdK1hvP8TacG6SsOZ2HxTZfQ8
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800

{
"identifier": {
"type": "dns",
"value": "shop.room801.com"
},
"status": "invalid",
"expires": "2023-11-27T16:11:51Z",
"challenges": [
{
"type": "http-01",
"status": "invalid",
"error": {
"type": "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized",
"detail": "159.65.238.59: Invalid response from https://shop.room801.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=well+known+acme+challenge+oQ1Mm2ADnD6NrI0Oh5XpYHoC99alCC6IETD4GmiC2nI\u0026404=1: "\r\n\u003c!doctype html\u003e\r\n\u003chtml class=\"use-header3\" lang=\"en\"\u003e\r\n    \u003chead \u003e\r\n        \u003cscript\u003e\n\tvar BASE_URL = WEB_URL = 'https://shop.r"",
"status": 403
},
"url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/285750384126/5YDEQw",
"token": "oQ1Mm2ADnD6NrI0Oh5XpYHoC99alCC6IETD4GmiC2nI",
"validationRecord": [
{
"url": "http://shop.room801.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/oQ1Mm2ADnD6NrI0Oh5XpYHoC99alCC6IETD4GmiC2nI",
"hostname": "shop.room801.com",
"port": "80",
"addressesResolved": [
"159.65.238.59"
],
"addressUsed": "159.65.238.59"
},
{
"url": "https://shop.room801.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=well+known+acme+challenge+oQ1Mm2ADnD6NrI0Oh5XpYHoC99alCC6IETD4GmiC2nI\u0026404=1",
"hostname": "shop.room801.com",
"port": "443",
"addressesResolved": [
"159.65.238.59"
],
"addressUsed": "159.65.238.59"
}
],
"validated": "2023-11-20T16:11:52Z"
}
]
}
2023-11-20 11:11:56,991:DEBUG:acme.client:Storing nonce: v0bMowfisrPp6g35giCZu_YsSwNdK1hvP8TacG6SsOZ2HxTZfQ8
2023-11-20 11:11:56,993:DEBUG:certbot.reporter:Reporting to user: The following errors were reported by the

Comment: I was able to fix one domain, but now have to fix the other one.